# How can I convert all HTML Entities and unicode chars to english equivalents for sorting in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replace, html-entities

I have database data that has special characters in both unicode and html entity format in the data. I need to sort the list of results alphabetically however, some of the unicode data and html entities mess up the alphabetical order (ie: &# comes before A when the code might be for an accented E which comes after A).

Currently, I'm just using a nested replace statement to generate a 'sort' column since I was under the impression there was a limited set of special characters used in the DB.

The client wants to be on the safe side and convert ALL characters on this page http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm into english equivalents before sorting...

Current code:

```
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(@Word, 'À', 'A') 
             , 'Â', 'A')
             , 'Ä', 'A')
             , 'Ç', 'C')
             , 'É', 'E')
             , 'È', 'E')
             , 'È', 'E')
             , 'Ê', 'E')
             , 'Î', 'I')
             , 'ï', 'i')
             , '&#216;', 'O')
             , '&#336;', 'o')
             , '&#193;', 'A')
             , '&#209;', 'N')
             , '&#237;', 'I')
             , '&#211;', 'O')
             , '&#323;', 'N')
             , '&#268;', 'C')
             , '&#225;', 'A')
             , '&#337;', 'O')
             , 'ő', 'o')
             , 'ö', 'o')
```

I realize this code is terribly inefficient - it started with only a couple of characters and then was added to over time.

What would be the best way to cycle through all the combinations on the page linked above?

Better yet, can someone confirm if the unicode values are sorted properly alphabetically and if so, is there a pre-built SQL Server 2005 function to just convert HTML Entities (friendly, numerical and hex versions) to Unicode for this column?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` and `COLLATE` to get the result you want with the accents:

```
SELECT
 CONVERT(varchar(50), N'æøåáäĺćçčéđńőöřůýţž')
 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI

returns aoaaalcccednooruytz
```

As far as HTML codes is concerned, I'd consider breaking out into a CLR Stored Procedure (or something in a 'proper' programming language) so that you can use the .NET libraries or similar.  Even better, I'd calculate the sort key in the program that inserts the data, and avoid doing this sort of string processing from within sql-server at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The new program has a sort field where the data enterer can just type the english version - doesn't help with the current 23,000 records though.

Comment: @tsdexter I'd write a little script (in C# or whatever) to work through the unpopulated records and correct the sort field.